# linq joining tables error

Tags: vb.net, linq

I got error when joining the table the return the result as list. Here are my codes. Please help. Thanks

```
Public Function GetMerchantList() As List(Of Merchant)
        Dim Db As New TTMSEntities

        Dim Data = From p In Db.TT_MERCHANT Join r In Db.TT_BRANCH_SETTING On _
                   p.MERCHANT_BRANCH_INTERNAL_NUM Equals r.INTERNAL_NUM
                   Select New With {p.MERCHANT_ID, p.DESCRIPTION, r.INTERNAL_NUM, r.BRANCH_DESC}

        If Data IsNot Nothing Then
            Return ConvertMerchant(Data)
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function
```

The error
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[VB$AnonymousType_0`4[System.String,System.String,System.Decimal,System.String]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TTMS.App.WebSites.Data.Merchant]

Comment: can you provide `ConvertMerchant` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `Data` variable have type `IQueryable` of anonymous type, so you need specify type what you want and call `ToList` something like this

```
Public Function GetMerchantList() As List(Of Merchant)
    Dim Db As New TTMSEntities

    Dim Data = (From p In Db.TT_MERCHANT Join r In Db.TT_BRANCH_SETTING On _
               p.MERCHANT_BRANCH_INTERNAL_NUM Equals r.INTERNAL_NUM
               Select New Merchant With {p.MERCHANT_ID, p.DESCRIPTION, r.INTERNAL_NUM, r.BRANCH_DESC}).ToList()

    If Data IsNot Nothing Then
        Return ConvertMerchant(Data)
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

also `Data` always not null (or Nothing for VB) it can be empty

Comment: Correct, but `Data` is never `Nothing`. It can be an empty list.

Comment: @GertArnold in end of answer i said the same :-)